# Rails installer on windows 8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, railsinstaller

I installed rubyinstaller 3.0 on my computer windows 8.1 and when I launch command line, I have the following message:

> DL is deprecated, please use fiddle.

When I created new project, I received this message :

"Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gem/rake-10.4.2.gem)
An error occured while installing rake -v '10.4.2', and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2' succeeds before bundling.

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: what happened when you tried to follow the instructions: `Make sure that gem install rake -v '10.4.2' succeeds` ?

Comment: You should follow the answer published by Robin : https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88 It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same issue a few days ago installing Ruby for the first time. I'm on Windows 10.

The "manual solution to SSL Issue" chapter tells you what to do. Fixed it for me:
https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Note: It still says DL is deprecated to me, but that's just a warning for something I have no knowledge about and didn't actually matter so far.

Comment: @Robin `DL deprecated` is a warning that the old `DL` library is deprecated and you should switch to `fiddle`. That warning is from `rb-readline` which used `dl` but has since been upgraded in more recent releases. *Mainly because `Ruby 2.2` dropped support for `DL` entirely.*